# Could not load type Error C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have 14 projects in my application. All projects are working fine except one. I am getting the error

> "Could not load type "source.exit.maincontrol" from "source.exit.main" version=6.0.0.0 " culture=neutral publickeytoken=null.

I migrated this application from .NET 1.1 to .NET  4.0. and this application works fine in .NET 1.1 but not in 4.0.

Because source.exit.main is the project in my application I have checked it has type maincontrol in it. Here are things's that also verified:

1. Checked the target platform that is 4.0 for every project.
2. Checked the dll present in the folder.
3. Checked the type it is present in the dll.
4. Every project is set to any CPU

Comment: Project added in References of whichever other project is calling it?

Comment: Check InnerException too, it may give you more information

Comment: What was your migration?  Did you use the Visual Studio conversion wizard, or did you re-create the project and re-add the source files?

Comment: Is this project referencing a debug DLL instead of release (or vice versa)?

Comment: Innerexception is null. project is referencing  debug dll.

Comment: I used VS conversion Wizard

Comment: @shree.pat18 Yes . there is another project calling it

Comment: Try creating a new project in the new version of Visual Studio and then include your existing source files in the new project, see if that yields better results.

Comment: Did you checked if your projects are using .NET 4.0 and not .NET 4.0 Client Profile ? I had a lot of issues because of that in the past.

Comment: @xDaevax . I did that but no success

Comment: @user1341210. Every project is using .NET 4.0